# How to remove Node and NPM completely from Linux Hosting through SSH

Tags: node.js, npm, server, cpanel

I've installed the Node and NPM on my Linux hosting using the following guide: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts

How can I noe remove it completely from the server?

I tried `npm uninstall npm -g` to remove NPM but got no error on SSH and **Aborted** on Terminal.

Then I removed the files with `rm -r bin/node bin/npm lib/node_modules nodejs`. It has killed the process but at this stage I'm not sure that I've completely removed the Node and NPM from server. As Symbolic link for NPM is already there.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) may be what you're looking for. The files should be in the same location.

Comment: Thank you for this. But I've already removed all the files. I think the only thing pending is to remove Symbolic link for npm command. I need help to remove it after removing all the files.